# Why does CSS file changes automatically in ExpressJS + NodeJS setup?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am developing a `NodeJS` + `ExpressJS` + `Jade` application.

I have a style.css file which I use like this.

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

All other `.jade` files extend `layout.jade`.

Problem is when I start my application, the CSS file gets edited automatically to an earlier state (some of the rules get removed). So I have to copy the newer rules back to the CSS file and then refresh the page to get those changes to apply.

What is causing this?

**EDIT:**

output of `find . -name style.\*`:

```
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/style.css
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib-cov/public/style.css
./public/stylesheets/style.css
./public/stylesheets/style.styl
```

Comment: from where do you copy the newwer rules back to the CSS file?  NodeJS, Express and Jade don't bring anything built-in auto reload mechanism. So do you use some additional libs?

Comment: @timaschew, oh, I just hit `Ctrl-Z` because my text editor can remember what my new rules were.

Comment: You tried another browser? Maybe your browser cache the old version?

Comment: @timaschew, but why would my browser rewrite to my source file? It would just show an older version from its cache. It shouldn't be rewriting anything.

Comment: I don't know, as I have already said: none of the libs you listed, brings the ability for this feature. Try to do reproduce this in a small isolated application only with this express and jade and no others libs.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details of how you have your app set up, I can only guess that you have some LESS or SASS middleware compiling things automatically and overwriting your style.css.

Have a look in your main server script for 'less' or 'sass'.
Are you using Grunt?  Have a look in your Gruntfile.js for 'less' or 'sass'.

If all else fails, try running a 'find' in your project directory.  Something like:

```
$ find ~/my-project -name style.\*
```

Conceivably it could be worth hunting for *.less or *.scss failing all the rest:

```
$ find ~/my-project -name \*.scss
$ find ~/my-project -name \*.less
```

Comment: That's your answer, your project is using Stylus: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/.  If you want to make changes to your CSS, you need to put them in style.styl.  Changes to style.css will get overwritten.